# GENESIS 4:3-4 - What type of offering?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, sacrifice

There were various offerings throughout the Old Testament. In the book of Job, we see burnt offerings to cover ‘sins’. During the wilderness, these were defined.

But, **what type of offering were Cain and Able performing in Genesis 4?**

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by your paragraph labelled (2), please. Are you attempting to express _sensus plenior_ by any chance ?

Comment: Easy answer, and short - Yes.

Comment: (1) There is no need to suggest 'hidden meaning'. It is patently clear that Cain had no respect to precedence - the sacrifice made in order to clothe his parents. But Abel _did_ have respect to precedence. Hence the difference. And hence God respected _neither_ Abel (himself) nor his offering. (2) They offered different offerings so there is no 'type' of offering relating to both.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. But, even your explanation ‘drew’ a lot of understanding from outside of the text, albeit not reliant on analysing the Hebraic aspects.
Some clarification, I was asking about the purpose of the offering. I accept that they both, albeit with different substance, had the same intent, or purpose for their offerings, but what was the offering for?
You seem? to be suggesting, by your connection to the animal skins God clothed Adam and Eve with, that the offering was for ‘sin covering’? But the fact that Abel sacrificed the ‘first born’ casts at least a little doubt  (for me.)

Comment: I would also like to understand what exactly are you asking. If these are two different questions, you can post them separately.

Comment: Cain's offering was מִנְחָה _minchah_ [Strong 4503](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/4503.htm). Abel's was הֶ֖בֶל וְאֶל־ _minhatow_ [Strong 4503](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/minchato_4503.htm). I don't know why both have one Strong number. I hope a Hebrew expert will assist.

Comment: @noam Fair comment, and I did consider doing that, that is, post just one part. But in the end, I thought/hoped that answering what the purpose of the sacrifice was, would then ‘lead into’ being able to understand how ‘respect’ ties in to this

Comment: Recall that in Gen 4 there were no Hebrews (yet) and that the codification of offering and sacrifice types had to await Sinai.  Therefore, I do not think the question can be answered.

Comment: Granted the ‘codification’ of various sacrifices are learnt about via the Sinai encounter, but there were sacrifices prior to this. And clearly they had a purpose, and were somehow ‘learnt’. So prior to Sinai, we see ‘sin’ offerings(Job), thanksgiving (Abraham), and for covenant. The most common deduction is Gen 4 was ‘sin’. But then it also ‘hints’ at first fruits/thanksgiving, - and I was hoping a deeper understanding of God having ‘respect’ towards it would help clarify it.

Comment: This question actually has a relatively easy answer. Embarrassingly, (for me.) it is answered, or rather clarified in the New Testament, in Hebrews.

Comment: The type of offering was immaterial. God said to Cain, "*If thou doest well, shalt thou not be accepted? and if thou doest not well, sin lieth at the door.*" (Genesis 4:7) God could only have said this to Cain if Cain understood what was required of him. So, Cain chose to offer that which he knew fell short of what was expected.

Comment: What is it we Christians offer to God for our sins if not the sacrifice of Christ, the Lamb of God prefigured in Able's gif, the Passover victim?  Those who offer God mere bread  and wine (the fruits of the earth that Cain offered) despoil their gift of its essential meaning expressed by Christ when He said, "This is my body...this is my blood."

Comment: Abel became a shepherd and Cain a farmer. Both brought to God a first-fruit of their labour. Able’s offering could serve as either a first-fruit offering, or a burnt-offering.  Cain obviously didn’t know that God valued a burnt-offering more than a first-fruit offering. However, he should have asked for an explanation instead of getting annoyed.